# Zooming in plotly-dash not following the mouse

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am using plotly-dash to do some data plotting.
However whenever I zoom, the rectangle of zooming does not follow closely the mouse while I am dragging it but instead takes other set size. (perhaps a set rate between height and width?)

Is there a way that the zoom rectangle follows the position of my mouse?